# VueJS - Object (user.fullName) as property on computed

Tags: vue.js

I search to compute **user.fullName** with **computed()** in VueJS 2.

The computed property must be in user object.

```
computed: {
  'user.fullName': () => {
    return `John Doe`
  }
}
```

It's doesn't works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `user` as computed property and dynamically add `fullName` to it. Real user object should be named differently:

```
computed: {
  user: () => {
    return {
      ...this.realUserObject,
      fullName: 'John Doe'
    }
  }
}
```